# What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for simplifying function iteration

Tags: matrices, cryptography

Taking for example, suppose there are now many butterfly diagrams stacked to form a multi-layer network. Obviously, when each computing unit is linear, the entire network can be simplified using a matrix operation, such as FFT.  It can be expressed as X=Fx, where F is a special Vandermonde matrix. When layer = n, $X=F^nx$.

Further more, when each computing unit is simple nonlinear, such as square or left right permutation,  it is also easy to analyze and obtain the final expression.

But when computing units become more complex, such as Sha-256 and AES, it seems extremely difficult to simplify it. There is a method called Walsh spectral analysis in AES, but it seems like it's just an approximation. Due to all known information and one-to-one correspondence between input and output, there must be a final expression. But what is the cost of finding this expression? Can this final expression reduce the total computational cost?

[a lay of butterfly diagram[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOhsQ.png)

Comment: FFT  has very regular structure that we want it as much as possible, on the other hand in Cryptography we want as much as possible controlled irregularity and [avalanche](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/136157/94479)

Comment: yes, FFT is just an example. In fact, the edges in the stacked graph are randomly generated. Besides, what you mentions is also related to the question: supposed the computing unit is AES, which already has the feature of avalanche, does the the stacked graph still need avalanche ?

Comment: AES has a regular structure considering the network of AES. This is the reason for affecting every output with the key as much as possible (avalanche).  The stacked graph is an example of the current setup due to the selected key. AES like any block cipher is a family of permutations, so it maps the input related to the selected permutation by the key.

Comment: Sea [TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm), IDEA..

Comment: i'm pretty sorry about that i know a little about crypto(just a few of teaching material) and that i'm not a native speaker, so i might misunderstand your idea. Here, the stack structure and its computing units do not work as an encryption function. They are tools to force the attacker to execute the calculation one unit by one unit.